# Video selection from gallery: Limit only videos up to 30 seconds should be selected

Tags: android, video, duration, onactivityresult

How can I control videos up to 30 seconds should be selected else show Toast/Popup.
I can get video's path in `onActivityResult` and can run video but can't get duration. Any suggestion, below is my code:

```
case Utils.REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_VIDEO:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedVieo = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVieo,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            try {
                if (filePath != null) {
                    runVideo(filePath);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this hope it helps

```
case Utils.REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_VIDEO:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedVieo = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVieo,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            try {
                if (filePath != null) {

                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(filePath));
                    int duration = mp.getDuration();
                    mp.release();

                    if((duration/1000) > 30){
                        // Show Your Messages                        
                    }else{
                        runVideo(filePath);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```