# Looking for Calculate Video size before Compressed Like WhatsApp

Tags: android

I am using https://github.com/RudreshJR/VideoCompression Code for Video Compressoin now require get size of video before start compressoion. something like WhatsApp.
Is it posible?

Comment: Look this its will helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293992/video-selection-from-gallery-limit-only-videos-up-to-30-seconds-should-be-selec

Comment: @archuMohan I am not looking for file size not time

Comment: @MikeJuker Yeah use this. It will compress video. You need to change some code as per your requirement.

Comment: for example video file size before compress 100MB and after compress 50MB, so i want compressed file size before i start compression like whatsup...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to calculate the estimated size of video when it is compressed, before you do the compression.

Maybe it is enough to use the ratio 25mb to 1mb?
So divide the video size with 25?

Comment: ratio not wokring

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this

File file = new File("xxx.flv");

long length = file.length();

length = length/1024;